# iOS - Fastest way to retrieve all <img> in an html string?

Tags: iphone, html, pattern-matching, image

I have many HTML strings (news items from google reader) to process. Majorly what I need to do is to retrieve all img tags from the HTMLs.

Can anyone tell me a most efficient way to do that?

Thanks

Also, what if I need to retrieve all  tags as well as

tags? Any fastest way to retrieve both or even more tags in one run?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try libtidy + NSXMLParser:

```
 doc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] 
           initWithContentsOfURL:url
                         options:(NSXMLNodePreserveWhitespace|NSXMLNodePreserveCDATA)
                           error:&err];
 if (!doc) {
     doc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] 
           initWithContentsOfURL:url
                         options:NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML
                           error:&err];
 }
```

From the doc, `NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML`: **Formats HTML into valid XHTML during processing of the document.**

If this doesn't work, you can try loading the HTML source into an UIWebView and use javascript to access the DOM.

Comment: Hi, actually this is what I am doing, tidy it first and then parse it. but it is very slow. It costs almost 0.5 - 0.9 sec for just ONE rss item (the length of the HTML is roughly 2KB - 10KB). If I do this for 50 items, it is about 1 minute.

Comment: You asked about HTML string. RSS is not an HTML string. Have you checked objective-c RSS parsers? The more specific, the faster, I guess.

Comment: NSXMLDocument is *not* available on iOS... not sure to follow

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the HTML strings are actually valid XML (i.e. they are actually XHTML), then you should consider using XPath to match all elements of the name "IMG". I've used various C libraries in an iOS application to do this kind of things successfully.

Comment: That's a pretty big assumption to make for random RSS items though.

Comment: True - It's an idea that would work only for XHTML pages and that makes it limited.

Comment: To clarify, this might still be the best method. It depends on your XML parser and how well it parses wellformed or malformed HTML.

Comment: @cobbal, thanks. but I can't assume that, in fact, many HTMLs from RSS items are not strict valid HTML. Also, if I construct a XHTML doc, it is much slower than pure string scan.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to try would be to use an NSScanner instances. Assuming you have your HTML string in an NSString called htmlString, you could try something like this:

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:htmlString];
while ([scanner scanUpToString:@"<img" intoString:NULL]) {
    NSString *tagContents;
    if ([scanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString &tagContents]) {
        // Do something with tag contents
    }
    else {
        // Do nothing? I think this would be hit on the last time through the loop
    }
}
```